# console.error() showing up as "Info" in Next.js project on Vercel

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

I am running a small Next.js 13 project on Vercel. When some exceptions happen, I handle them and use `console.error()` to log something to the logs.

In the Vercel Logs, I'm seeing these show up with the level "Info" (so they're not highlighted red). I see one of the libraries I'm using printing at an "Error" level, but I haven't been able to work out what they're doing (looks like `console.log()`).

I can't see any settings in Vercel to fix this. Is it a Next.js configuration issue?

Thanks